# What better way to combine (integrate) javaFX with spring for build desktop applications

Tags: spring, javafx

What we understand is that javafx has its own thread to execute the application. While the spring framework was also the case. Then how best and safest way to combine it? Is the spring run on the start method belonging to javafx, or javafx that runs in the spring.

Comment: Spring doesn't "have its own thread"

Comment: Thank you James. I was wrong about Spring thread..he..he..

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this repository using Spring Boot.

https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-labs/tree/master/spring-boot-javafx

But do you really need Spring ? there are many other frameworks dedicated to JavaFX and providing same features in a more convenient way.

Comment: If you want to have a JavaFX application that respect threading concerns, you should have a look to JRebirth AF, it allows to run UI task automatically into UI thread and all long task into a thread pool.
Some other tasks are run into a dedicated thread to manage events listening.
It also provides a component modularization with injection replacing lightweight container of Spring.